# How to prove that this recurrence is equal to nlogn?

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation

This is a question from CLRS book, I have to prove that the following recurrence -:

$T(n) = 2T(n/2)  + n$

is $nlog(n)$ when $n = 2^k$ and $k \gt 1$

**What I have tried-:**

Putting n = $2^k$

I get the following expression:

$T(2^k) = 2T(2^k/2) + 2^k$

further simplified into

$T(2^k) = 2T(2^{k-1}) + 2^k$

but then I am stuck.

I have seen proofs for this question but they all involve $k+1$ instead of using $k$, why do they do that?

I would appreciate it if I could be told what mathematical concept is used so that I can study it further.

Comment: Two comments: You can't prove that the recurrence is equal to $n \log n$ (what does that even mean), only that the solution to the recurrence or the function satisfying the recurrence is $n \log n$. The recurrence is the equation itself. Second: Do you know mathematical induction?

Comment: @Dylan Heard of it, but don't know how to use it. Also could you please elaborate what you mean by "only that the solution to the recurrence or the function satisfying the recurrence is $nlogn$"? Does that mean that the answer to the recurrence is same as $nlog(n)$? What do you mean by the function satisfying the recurrence what does that mean?

Comment: What I mean is that what you wrote is the equivalent of writing that $x^2 + 7 = (x + 1)^2 + 2$ is equal to $2$. It's not the equation that is equal to $2$, it is the solution. In other words, it's not $x^2 + 7 = (x + 1)^2 + 2$ that is equal to $2$, it's $x$ that is equal to $2$. It's a language issue more than a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not know, how to use mathematical induction, this proof will be made with a bit of hand waving. By using the recurrence relation for $T(n)$, $T(n/2)$ ... we obtain

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
T(n) &=& n + 2T(n/2) \qquad (=\color{red}{1}\cdot n + 2^{\color{red}{1}}T(n/2^{\color{red}{1}})) \\
     &=& n + 2(n/2 + 2T(n/4)) \\
     &=& 2n + 4T(n/4) \qquad (=\color{red}{2}\cdot n + 2^{\color{red}{2}}T(n/2^{\color{red}{2}}))\\
     &=& 2n + 4(n/4 + 2T(n/8)) \\
     &=& 3n + 8T(n/8) \qquad (=\color{red}{3}\cdot n + 2^{\color{red}{3}}T(n/2^{\color{red}{3}}))\\
     &=& \cdots \\
     &=& \color{red}{k}\cdot n + 2^{\color{red}{k}}T(n/2^{\color{red}{k}}))
\end{eqnarray}
$$
When do we finish? Well, in addition to the recurrence relation, one typically specifies the initial condition that defines $T(1)$, so we will assume that we also know what is $T(1)$.

Hence, at the end $k$ has the value, such that $n/2^k = 1\Leftrightarrow n = 2^k \Leftrightarrow k =\log_2 n$. Then, the last line reads as $\log_2 n \cdot n + n \cdot T(1) = n(\log_2 n + T(1))$.

Typically, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so this proof does not work for all numbers (what is $T(3)$?). This is the point when the induction should be used and that is why all the other proves of the similar problems use $k  + 1$.

You should really learn how to use it!

Comment: I don't get it how that is equal to $n\log(n)$. I can understand that at every stage that $n$ is broken into $n/2$ but then how are you getting $n\log(n)$?

Comment: How is it simplified into $n + n + n + n$?

Comment: @ng.newbie You are missing the dots at the end. I will edit the answer

Comment: If you do that please know that I have a very poor math background hence if you could please be verbose in your explanation. Favouring sentences for equations.